# C# - Window always on top problem

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, overlay, always-on-top

So i'm making an overlay, and I need it to be always on top. To do so, i just set

```
chackBox1.checked = true;

private void checkChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        this.TopMost = checkBox1.Checked;
}
```

as it is suggested in many places. The problem here is 
1) I need a checkbox button... but thats not rly an issue, I can set to to Visible = false.
2) It never works untill I manually check the box with my mouse! Even if I set it to checked, set form1.isTopMost = true (after initComponents) and call the checkChanged event, I always have to manually check the box before it always stays on top!

please help! How do I make it so that the overlay loads up always on top?

My next step is making a thread that will force the form to stay on top, but I would like to avoid this LOL

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: Why aren't you just setting TopMost in the property inspector of the form and drop the checkbox?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the property inspector, can you give me more details please? I used the checkbox control because that is what all examples used

Comment: @David: He means the properties of the control in Visual Studio.

Comment: I tried, it gives out the same results

Comment: @David: What about calling .Show() on the TopMost form after you set TopMost = true?

Comment: Ok, what I did if set TopMost = true on both focus and unfocus events for my window and it seems to work, after I .Show() the windows after init! Thannks for the help guys!

Comment: @David: You should make that the answer and accept it

Comment: I did! :D gave you the point! thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something else wrong. Those property change events fire whenever the property value changes, regardless of whether this was done by your code, by the control's own code or databinding. If checked is already true, it may not fire the handler until the check box state changes.

You should fire off a MessageBox in your `checkChanged(..)` event to display when you programmatically set checkBox1 to true or check the checkbox manually. This will assist in debugging. Since checkChanged isn't the typical default name for this type of event, my guess is that you changed it so it could be pointing to a different event handler function altogether.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `Topmost = true` on `getfocus` and `lostfocus` works apparantly till you have a message box popping up from some EXE you are running, clicking on the top bar of the popup message box would take your window to background.

Try this, a VERY robust way of achieving this:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication52
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
        static readonly IntPtr HWND_NOTOPMOST = new IntPtr(-2);
        static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOP = new IntPtr(0);
        static readonly IntPtr HWND_BOTTOM = new IntPtr(1);
        const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
        const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
        const UInt32 TOPMOST_FLAGS = SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetWindowPos(this.Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, TOPMOST_FLAGS);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys! Thanks for the help, I will give the answer to 0A0D since he triggered it!

I set TopMost = true on both focus and unfocus event for the window, and I use .Focus() and .Show after initialization, and everything seems to work!

Thanks!

Comment: I appreciate the accept but yours is the one which fixed it. I am glad I helped either way.